# How to limit what gets returned with fields.list in Flask-RestPlus

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

Every building has units and every unit is associated with an account. There can be many accounts associated with a unit. There can only be one account per unit with a status of "active".

The API returns a list of all the units, and nested within each unit is a list of *all* the accounts associated with that unit.

How can I return the same list of units but only the *active* account associated with each?

```
#model.py

class Unit(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'units'
    ...
    building_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('buildings.id'))
    building = db.relationship("Building", back_populates="units")
    accounts = db.relationship("Account", back_populates="unit")

class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(sqlalchemy_utils.ChoiceType(STATUS_CHOICES))
    ...

#building.py

@api.route('/units')
class BuildingUnits(Resource):
    @api.marshal_with(schemas.unit_fields, envelope='data')
    def get(self):
        """ Get list of all units
        """
        return rbac.current_identity.building.units

#schemas.py

unit_fields = api.model('unit_fields', {
    'id': fields.String,
    ...etc
    ...etc
    'accounts': fields.List(fields.Nested(account_fields)),
})

account_fields = api.model('account_fields', {
    'id': fields.String,
    ...etc
    ...etc
    'status': fields.String(attribute=lambda x: getattr(x.status, 'value', 'Inactive')),
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking someone (who Im not sure wants me to publicize who it is)

He responded as follows:

> This is actually a good example why I tend to prefer to not use
>   extensions to handle the API payloads. Sooner or later you find
>   something that you need isn’t directly supported and you end up having
>   to create compromise solutions.
>
> What I would do in your case, is define a @property in your model that
>   is maybe called active_account. This would be implemented as a
>   database query that returns that one account that you want singled
>   out. Then you can add “active_account” to your schema, so that
>   Flask-RESTful renders it as a related item.
>
> Hope this helps.

I think it was a great answer and it solved my problem.

I then followed up with:

> Im not quite sure what you're referring to when you said: "why I tend
>   to prefer to not use extensions to handle the API payloads."
>
> Which extension are you referring to.  What exactly would you do to
>   implement what I have without using "extensions"

and he responded:

> You are using Flask-RESTful, that is the extension I was referring to.
>   I really have nothing against Flask-RESTful, works well, but I prefer
>   to write my APIs in straight Flask.

And thats all folks, maybe later Ill post how I implemented what he said.